# need help, bug in query select with isnull

Tags: select, activerecord, yii2, isnull

i think this can be a bug in yii2, 
when i use:

```
$query->select ("isnull(cba.HSLET,0)");
$query->join('INNER JOIN','cba','cba.id = regverification.cba_id');
```

> yii miss create the sql sentence resulting in a error near:
>
> isnull(cba.HSLET, [0)]

Comment: Dude, it's IFNULL, not ISNULL here...

Comment: in mssql server you can use both, but the problem is not the function, is yii

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Yii 2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html):

> Besides column names, you can also select DB expressions. You must use the array format when selecting a DB expression that contains commas to avoid incorrect automatic name quoting.

So it should be:

```
$query->select(["ISNULL(cba.HSLET, 0)"]);
```